# How to get all strings of length=n from the characters in a list in python

Tags: python, list, character, combinations, permutation

I would like to know a simple and pythonic way to get all strings of length *n* that are composed of the characters contained in a list called *L*.

For example:

```py
L = ['0','1']
n = 3
```

How do I get:

```
['000','001','010','011','100','101','110','111']
```

A possible solution is by using `itertools.product`. It works, but it's not very elegant, so I'm looking for a more pythonic solution.
Here's how it would be:

```
L = ['0','1']
n = 3
a = [L for i in range(n)]
x = list(itertools.product(*a))
x = ["".join(i) for i in x]
```

The resulting list looks like this:

```
>>> x
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Is there something built-in like `all_possible_strings(L, n)`, which takes the elements in *L* and obtains all possible combinations of length *n* with those elements?

Answer (score 2):

Using the repeat option of [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) seems to give you what you want more directly:

```
L = ['0','1']
n = 3
x = list(itertools.product(L, repeat=n))
x = ["".join(i) for i in x]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code with Python 2.6 and above ONLY

**First, import itertools:**

```
import itertools
```

**Permutation (order matters):**

```
print list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4),
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

**Documentation:**

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Happy Coding

Comment: This is not really suitable for my case, although it's a good suggestion. In my case, *L* is shorter than *n* (i.e. I have 2 elements in my list but I want strings that are of length 3).